# Android: Questions about update and sync

Tags: android

I want to ask a few things:

1) Which would be better to update the database and the application itself and how?

When I start the phone to my receiver and service to pull in a certain time new events, before the application start.

2) make auto / manual sync. and how?

3) and when I create an new event must send it to the server which will update based there;

4) When you create a new event on a server I have to send it through the poll / push service, and what with who? how

5) When to use: AsyncTask; where the threads;

Answer (score 0):

Hard to understand your questions, my attempt to awnser:

1) Check this sync example: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/index.html

2) Check the same example as (1)

3) Event? Get information about remote procedure calls (Android JSON RPC). Heres an example open-source project http://code.google.com/p/android-json-rpc/

4) uh, same as (3) I guess.

5) Use AsyncTask to perform operations that arn't directly related to the user interface. For more information (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)